# Render WooCommerce Handpicked Products Block from a plugin

Tags: woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks, wordpress-plugin-creation

In the plugin code I have:

```php
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'show_widget');
function show_widget(){
        $block_name = 'woocommerce/handpicked-products';
        $converted_block = new WP_Block_Parser_Block( $block_name, array(
            'query' => new WP_Query( array ( 
                'post__in' => $products, // $products is a given array of product IDs
                'post_type' => 'product'            
            ) )
        ), array(), '', array() );
        $serialized_block = serialize_block( (array) $converted_block );
        echo $serialized_block;
}
```

as a result, i see a ***commented out*** `wp:query` when I view source:

[image]

yet nothing is actually painted on the page. Notice ***there is*** one product in the result set and I expected it to be rendered to the screen.

Why doesn't it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

switched `serialize_block` with `render_block` and it works...